# Python pandas to get specified rows from a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to read a very large set of data from a CSV file using pandas in python. I need to break up the data into parts to take it in, therefore I would like to take in half of the rows first and then the other half.

I see that there is the chunksize parameter in the read_csv. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to put it all into a matrix or sparse matrix after it is read.

```
wow = pd.read_csv('TestingCSV.csv', sep=',', header='infer', low_memory=False, chunksize=10, usecols=(range(3, 5)))
```

This returns a type: `<class 'pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader'>`

What is a possible way to take in the different chunks and then reconstruct a matrix or sparse matrix from them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `read_csv` you need to read the whole file you can't read part of it.

When it comes down to the `chunksize`, you need to take those "chunks" that are listed under `wow` and [`concat()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html).

For example:

```
chunks = pd.read_csv(data, chunksize = 100)
df = pd.concat(chunks, ignore_index=True)
```

So now you have a the full dataframe and you can do whatever analysis you need to do.

It's also an iterable object, so you can do the following:

```
for chunk in chunks:
    #do something to each chunk
```

Comment: Thank you very much. 

I was missing this part: ignore_index=True